# Update state to determine if a container is in view

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement Infinite Scroll in React and I want the URL to change as soon as the one container ends and another one starts.
If I scroll up and view the previous container, URL should change back.

**What I did:** I have implemented the Infinite Scroll successfully. And am trying to find the position of the container depending on the height of the container and window.scrollY value on page.

I need to update the values in State for that reason and I have used window.onscroll inside render to check for conditions and update the state accordingly.

**What is the problem:** I am facing issues that I am not getting desired results and I know that I should not be using setState inside render(). But where else can I update the state, if that has to be done depending upon the conditions in window.onscroll that is inside render().

### Update

*InfiniteScrollingComponent.js*

```
state = {
    height: [],
    containerThatIsBeingRenderedArr: [],
    elementIndex: 0,
    upperBound: 0,
    lowerBound: null
};

componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
    let urlArr = [], height = [], containerThatIsBeingRenderedArr = [];
    for (let index in this.props.items) {
      containerThatIsBeingRenderedArr[index] = document.getElementById(
        `${this.props.items[index].slug}`
      );
      height[index] = containerThatIsBeingRenderedArr[index].offsetHeight;
    }
    if (prevState.containerThatIsBeingRenderedArr.length === containerThatIsBeingRenderedArr.length) return;
    if (containerThatIsBeingRenderedArr.length && height.length) {
      this.setState(
        {
          height: height,
          containerThatIsBeingRenderedArr: containerThatIsBeingRenderedArr
        }
      );
    }
};
```

Then inside render() method, I have:

```
window.onscroll = () => {
    this.changeURL();
}
```

changeURL method looks like this:

```
changeURL = () => {
    const { elementIndex, height, upperBound, lowerBound } = this.state;
    let LB = lowerBound === null ? height[0] : lowerBound;
    if (window.scrollY > upperBound && window.scrollY < LB) {
       return;
    }
    if (window.scrollY > LB) {
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          upperBound: prevState.lowerBound,
          lowerBound: LB + prevState.height[prevState.elementIndex + 1],
          elementIndex: prevState.elementIndex + 1
        };
      });
    }
    if (window.scrollY < upperBound) {
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          lowerBound: prevState.upperBound,
          upperBound:
            prevState.upperBound - prevState.height[prevState.elementIndex - 1],
          elementIndex: prevState.elementIndex - 1
        };
      });
    }
};
```

Comment: can you create an example to show the issue?

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful

Comment: @PriyeshKumar, I have updated the question to include the required code.

Comment: @Sagivb.g I have updated the question to include the required code.

Comment: I don't see you changing state in `render`.

Comment: `changeURL()` is called inside `window.onscroll()`, which in turn is inside `render()`

Comment: @KapilSharma it's not a problem. It only called in `onscroll` event not while rendering so it's not an issue.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielTran. You were right, the problem was with me calling changeUrl inside render, thanks for helping.

Comment: Thanks, @Sulthan, you were right as well.